# How and where should invest poor country's employee to get $1 million in 20 years

Tags: profitability, learning, earned-income

In the poor country, an employee has ~$300 monthly salary and $200 monthly is enough not to die from the hunger. 
How to use remaining $100 to get rid of his poverty and to start having $2000-$5000 monthly as American has?

Comment: You can't get $1 million by investing $100 a month for 20 years. That would need an annual return of about 32.3%, which is completely unachievable. The actual amount invested is only $24,000.

Comment: But I believe that person can reinvest ~50% of his profit, increasing that actual invested amount.

Comment: Make sure your financial goals match the outcomes you want to achieve. If you only need $200 monthly for living expenses, at retirement you would only need ~ $100,000 to invest everything in simple 2% interest-earning investments, to be able to afford your living expenses off of pure low-risk interest earnings. That $100,000 alone is quite a feat, and could be achieved in about 30 years, earning ~7% average returns on an investment portfolio contributing $100 / month.

Comment: "How to use remaining $100 to get rid of his poverty and to start having $2000-$5000 monthly as American has?"  The simple answer is to be an immigrant - move to somewhere with a lot of money and growth, like China, Korea, Singapore, etc.  This has been the "story of life" forever.

Comment: @EugeneKaurov Assuming you reinvest *all* the interest, you still need an annual return of over 27%, which is also completely unrealistic.

Answer (score 3):

Any traditional or safe investment like bonds is not going to take you anywhere near 1 million dollars. So is the case with shares or other similar instruments. For example, when I checked monthly investment of 100$ compounded at 5% for 20 years, the figure roughly touched 50,000$.

Only one possible way I can think of is investing in own skills and finding a better job. Nowadays, one does not need to travel to US to work for a US firm. There are plenty of offshore opportunities. Depending upon your educational background, you may want to try hard to find a better job. Once you start to earn at least few thousand dollars a month, you should be in a better position to plan long term investments.

Simple rule is this: Invest on yourself.